# Two Layouts Overlapping When Switching Tabs in Android

Tags: android

I have run into an obstacle where my tabbed layouts are overlapping their content.  I am currently creating an Android app.  This is when the first tab is opened.  (link to picture below):

http://oi39.tinypic.com/330r8nq.jpg

This is what happens when I open the second tab (link to picture below):

http://oi39.tinypic.com/9fzl02.jpg

You might notice that the button that says "Button" is overlapping the MainActivity.  That is my problem.  I don't want them to overlap.  I just want the button to show the other activity (no overlapping).  Here is part of my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("Created By Rohit Nandakumar");
    actionBar.setTitle("Currency Converter"); 
    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab Frag1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Converter");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Currencies");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("News");

    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();

    Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1));
    Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment2));
    Frag3.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment3));

    actionBar.addTab(Frag1);
    actionBar.addTab(Frag2);
    actionBar.addTab(Frag3);
```

Here is Fragment1.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is my Fragment2.java code:

```
    package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is my MyTabsListener.java file:

```
    package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MyTabsListener implements TabListener {

    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }




    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }



}
```

What is the problem?  What am I doing wrong.  I have searched Google, but I could not find the solution.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my Logcat:

```
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.currencyconverter/com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:582)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at   android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)  
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:575)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:499)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:485)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-26 21:18:38.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     ... 11 more
06-26 21:18:46.173: I/Process(2890): Sending signal. PID: 2890 SIG: 9
06-26 21:19:07.554: E/Trace(2944): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-26 21:19:08.233: D/dalvikvm(2944): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 11% free 2619K/2912K, paused 71ms+3ms, total 138ms
```

If I add commit, the method looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to add `commit()` to your FragmentTransaction? Example: `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();`?

Comment: To the fragments file?

Comment: Please show me an example of how it would look like.

Comment: Inside your `onTabSelected` method, where you replace the current `Fragment`. And I've already added the code in the end of the first comment ;-)

Comment: Now, my app is crashing.

Comment: @Darwind Now, my app is crashing.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @Darwind I have posted the Logcat (stacktrace)

Comment: So what did you add exactly to the `onTabSelected` method? How does it look now?

Comment: @Darwind I have added the OnTabSelected Method.

Comment: @Darwind  I have added the OnTabSelected Method.

Comment: Could you by any chance zip the project and upload it somewhere where I can download it and see if I can fix it that way?